# Live USB won't boot

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I created a live USB using the live USB creator so that I could install Kubuntu. However, when I attempt to boot into it, I get a message that says:

```
Secure boot not enabled
```

How can I enable secure boot, or is there another workaround?

I have a MacBook Pro from early 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable SecureBoot within the BIOS.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot